# How to access the json https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/tags/hashtag/sections/?

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

does anybody know how to access or request [https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/tags/{}/sections/](https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/tags/%7B%7D/sections/) where {} is a random hashtag to return a result?
I know depending on the user-agent you can access it, but every user agent i have tried which is not working.

The only way i can access it is with selenium-wire and selenium and that is hit and miss.

currently using python 3.9.4 , selenium wire to login

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to figure out an Instagram username from the user id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58354392/how-to-figure-out-an-instagram-username-from-the-user-id)

Comment: i have tried that already but the main problem i forgot to write is i think for this api call you need to be logged in

Comment: @kk16383 yes, you must be logged in to use this API.